# Serenity BDD : How to loop on Steps with Soft Assertions

Tags: java, serenity-bdd, assertj

I need to run tests on an array of datas, and I can't find a way to do a soft assert in my step AND show the error at the correct step in the Serenity Report.

### Example code

```
@Then("All my datas are correct")
public void verifyMyDatas(){

    int[] myDataArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4};

    for(int i = 0; i < myDataArray.length; i++){

        mySteps.myAwesomeValidator(myDataArray[i]);
    }
}
```

And an example step :

```
@Step("Checking the value {0}")
public void myAwesomeValidator(int value){

    //I need a soft assertion here
}
```

### My attempt :

I tried using the assertj framework. But my problem with it is that the "All my datas are correct" step is correctly flagged as a FAILURE, but all the substeps "Checking the value X" are marked as SUCCESSes on Serenity's report.

my test code :

```
@Then("All my datas are correct")
public void verifyMyDatas(){

    SoftAssertions softAssertion = new SoftAssertions();

    int[] myDataArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4};

    for(int i = 0; i < myDataArray.length; i++){
```

my           mySteps.myAwesomeValidator(myDataArray[i], softAssertion);
        }

```
    softAssertion.assertAll();
}
```

And the step :

```
@Step("Checking the value {0}")
public void myAwesomeValidator(int value, SoftAssertions softAssertion){

    softAssertion.assertThat(value < 3).isTrue();
}
```

Edit : tried to clarify the problem with my attempt

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing the point but you can instantiate `SoftAssertions softly = new SoftAssertions();` above and then iterate the array (like with that for loop) and inside loop call `softly.assertThat ...` and after loop say `softly.assertAll();`.
Hope it helps, if not please tell :)

Comment: @doom4s It does indeed report that the step "All my datas are correct" failed, but It reports all the sub steps ("checking the value X") as successes, and I would like to know exactly which failed, not just the entire test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try [`as()`](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#as-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to describe the assertion and not introduce a `Step` to see if it works (I believe it should):

```
@Then("All my datas are correct")
public void verifyMyDatas(){

  SoftAssertions softAssertion = new SoftAssertions();

  int[] myDataArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
  for(int i = 0; i < myDataArray.length; i++) {
    myAwesomeValidator(myDataArray[i], softAssertion); 
  }

  softAssertion.assertAll();
}

public void myAwesomeValidator(int value, SoftAssertions softAssertion){

  // use as() to describe the assertion 
  softAssertion.assertThat(value)
               .as("awesomely validate value %d", value);
               .isLessThan(3);
}
```

Comment: Serenity doesn't show in its report those "as" as steps (which is kinda logical but would be cool), but at least it outputs a list which shows exactly where it failed. It's better than what I have right now, thank you